# Keynote and Pages File Location on Ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Are the files accessible from an SDK API call?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Keynote, Pages or Numbers are given the same special treatment that Photos gets. You can write an app that can open a file that it has created in one of these apps. But opening documents in another app's sandbox is typically not supported.